# How to prove that$\sum_{n\le x}(\psi(\frac xn)-\vartheta(\frac xn))\Lambda (n)=O (x) $

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that $$\sum_{n\le x}(\psi(\frac xn)-\vartheta(\frac xn))\Lambda (n)=O (x) $$

After some calculations, l arrived to $$O (\sqrt{x}\log x\sum_{m=1}^\infty x^{\frac 1m} (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^m)$$

So l need to evaluate that sum. Could anyone help me, please?

> Remark: This question is related to problem 4.22 in Apostol's book. The problem is requested to prove that Selberg's asymptotic formula is equivalent to
>
> $$\vartheta (x)\log x+\sum_{p\le x}\vartheta (\frac xp)\log p=2x\log x+O (x) $$
>
> My idea was to first show that
>
> $$\vartheta (x)\log x+\sum_{n\le x}\vartheta (\frac xn)\Lambda (n)=2x\log x+O (x) $$
>
> Thus, i've needed to show that
>
> $$\sum_{n\le x}(\psi(\frac xn)-\vartheta(\frac xn))\Lambda (n)=O (x) $$

Comment: What are $\psi,\theta, \Lambda$?

Comment: I'm really curious where you've got this $1/\sqrt{2}$ in the exponent, let alone its power...

Comment: @Wojowu I've edited that.

Comment: The sum is at least as big as its first term, which is $\Omega(x)$, so the entire thing cannot be in $O(x)$

Comment: @EdwardH. $\psi(x)-\vartheta(x)$ is $O(\sqrt{x})$. Even then, $\Omega(x)$ doesn't exclude $O(x)$

Comment: @Wojowu Oh I mean the last sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{n\le x}(\psi(\frac xn)-\vartheta(\frac xn))\Lambda (n)=O(\sum_{n \le x}(\frac xn)^{1/2} (\psi(n+1)-\psi(n)))\\ = O(\psi(x)+\sum_{n \le x}((\frac xn)^{1/2}-(\frac x{n+1})^{1/2}) \psi(n)) $$

$$ = O(x+\sum_{n \le x}((\frac xn)^{1/2}-(\frac x{n+1})^{1/2}) n)= O(x+\sum_{n \le x} (\frac xn)^{1/2}) = O(x)$$

where I used $\psi(x)-\psi(x/2) = O(\log {x\choose x/2} ) = O(x)$,

$\psi(x) = O(x)$,  $\psi(x)-\vartheta(x) = O(x^{1/2})$ and partial summation.

Comment: Thanks. I've provd the relation $\psi (x)-\vartheta (x) =O (\sqrt x) $ using prime number theorem like below $$\psi (x)-\vartheta (x) =\sum_{m=2}^{\log_2x}\sum_{p\le x^{1/m}}\log p=O (\sum_{p\le\sqrt x}\log p)=O (\frac {\sqrt x}{\log\sqrt x}\log\sqrt x)=O (\sqrt x)$$ Does there exist a proof without use of PNT ?

Comment: The proof is $\psi(x)-\psi(x/2) = O(\log {x\choose x/2} ) = O(x)$

Comment: I looked to chapter 4 in Apostol's book several times but couldn't find any relation between $\psi (x)-\psi ( x/2) $ and $\psi (x)-\vartheta (x) $. Could you please say me how they are related? Where does the $\log {x\choose x/2} $ come from? Should l see another book?

Comment: The proof should be $\psi (x)=\vartheta (x)+\vartheta (\sqrt x)+\vartheta (\sqrt [3] x )+\cdots $.